How to deploy next.js 14 application on namecheap vps with no nodejs setup tool
I have a namecheap VPS host that uses :
AlmaLinux v8.10.0 STANDARD kvm
cPanel Version
120.0.9
and I have a problem in deploying my nextjs application in it .
I followed this guide :
https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/how-to-install-a-node.js-application/
and it worked but the redirects in it aren't working and after some debugging and trying to build on the local the I figured that the problem is in the way I am deploying my application on the server (it is working on local with no issues) .
so I hope that there is a way to fix it
